# CXF: How to supply SSL certificate dynamically?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, cxf, ssl-certificate

I have a generated CXF 2.7.10 client for SOAP SSL WebService.
How to I specify a private key/certificate (ideally in pem format) at runtime for it instead of hardcoding JKS in XML configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [blog post](http://ashakirin.blogspot.com/2013/04/cxf-security-getting-certificates-from.html) wherein an implementation of the [WSS4J](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/) [`Crypto`](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/ws/security/components/crypto/Crypto.html) interface is created by extending **CryptoBase**, obtaining the public keys from a centralized PKI store and the private key from the default crypto provider (**Merlin**) in a local keystore as usual.

In your case, assuming you want to continue using the default keystore for the public keys, you would flip the public/private key retrieval implementation around.

Source code references: WSS4J's [Merlin.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j/1.6.1/org/apache/ws/security/components/crypto/Merlin.java) extends [CryptoBase.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j/1.6.1/org/apache/ws/security/components/crypto/CryptoBase.java#CryptoBase)